# Oracle sql Get users with value in MONDAY field IF TODAY is MONDAY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has field names for each day of the week. I am trying to write a sql query that will get all users who don't have a null value in their day of the week field for the current weekday.

For example get all users from my table who's 'Monday' field is not null IF TODAY is MONDAY.

It will run everyday, so it needs to assess what day of the week it is everyday and get the corresponding users for that day.

I found this code snippet to get the day of the week but I am not sure how to use to within another select statement:

```
select to_char(sysdate,'D') from dual
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edited to add sample data and output:

```
USER | 123456
SUNDAY | 
MONDAY | 18
TUESDAY | 
WEDNESDAY | 15
THURSDAY | 
FRIDAY | 
SATURDAY | 11   
 ---
USER | 789023
SUNDAY | 18
MONDAY | 
TUESDAY | 3
WEDNESDAY | 15
THURSDAY | 
FRIDAY | 
SATURDAY | 11
```

So on Monday the Output would be:

```
  USER | 123456
```

On Tuesday the output would be:

```
 USER | 789023
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output for that data.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach - Added

Comment: Your data seems strange. Is first column table columns, and second column table rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

Assume that you have your table have 7 columns name `sunday`, `monday`, ...

```
SELECT user_column --user_id
FROM table_name
WHERE (
        TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 1 AND sunday IS NOT NULL
        OR TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 2 AND monday IS NOT NULL
        OR TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 3 AND tuesday IS NOT NULL
        OR TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 4 AND wednesday IS NOT NULL
        OR TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 5 AND thursday IS NOT NULL
        OR TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 6 AND friday IS NOT NULL
        OR TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'D') = 7 AND saturday IS NOT NULL
    );
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR( datevalue, 'D' )` is dependent on the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter and different territories have different first days of the week. Users can change this parameter in their own sessions and will have different defaults depending on their location when they installed the database so this method is going to have issues when used internationally.

Comment: @TM3 Run `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'DENMARK';` and you will get the wrong day's results as Monday is the first day of the week in Denmark (and many other territories).

Comment: @TM3 As in @MTO's comment, you should consider change to use `TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )` for comparison, as for my query has risk in output wrong result when your database has change (manually set `NLS_TERRITORY` or when you change to use database from other provider with diffirent config in OS`. Refer to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/initparams132.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )` to get the day of the week as a number (0 = Monday, 6 = Sunday) and this is independent of the NLS session parameters

Using:

- `TO_CHAR( datavalue, 'D' )` will give different first days of the week in different territories; and
- `TO_CHAR( datevalue, 'DAY' )` will give different values in different languages;
- But using `TRUNC( datevalue, 'IW' )` is independent of all those issues).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8df91/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  "USER"    INT,
  SUNDAY    INT,
  MONDAY    INT,
  TUESDAY   INT,
  WEDNESDAY INT,
  THURSDAY  INT,
  FRIDAY    INT,
  SATURDAY  INT
);

INSERT INTO table_name
SELECT 123456, NULL, 18, NULL, 15, NULL, NULL, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 789023, 18, NULL, 3, 15, NULL, NULL, 11 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT "USER",
         CASE TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'IW' )
         WHEN 0 THEN MONDAY
         WHEN 1 THEN TUESDAY
         WHEN 2 THEN WEDNESDAY
         WHEN 3 THEN THURSDAY
         WHEN 4 THEN FRIDAY
         WHEN 5 THEN SATURDAY
         WHEN 6 THEN SUNDAY
         END AS value
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  value IS NOT NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8df91/1/0)**:

```
|   USER | VALUE |
|--------|-------|
| 123456 |    15 |
| 789023 |    15 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This query returns the abbreviated day (Sun - Sat):

```
select to_char(sysdate,'DY') from dual;
```

It's easier to test.

You can write the query which returns the right colum like this:

```
select case to_char(sysdate,'DY') 
    when 'MON' then monday
    when 'TUE' then tuesday
    when 'WED' then wednesday
    when 'THU' then thursday
    when 'FRI' then friday
    when 'SAT' then saturday
    when 'SUN' then sunday
    else NULL
end 
from yourtable;
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain how this works in getting the users with values for today?

Comment: `TO_CHAR( datevalue, 'DY' ) is dependent on the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` session parameter. Users can change this parameter in their own sessions and will have different defaults depending on their location when they installed the database so this method is going to have issues when used internationally.

Answer (score 0):

By Using `Connect By level`, you may get the days of the week with corresponding numbers :

```
select to_char(sysdate+level,'D','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Turkish') "Day No", 
       to_char(sysdate+level,'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Turkish') "Day(Of Week)"
  from dual 
connect by level <= 7 
order by 1;
```

Also, a view may be created for using the values like a table as ( *NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE parameter may be related with your local settings* ):

```
create view v_days as
select to_char(sysdate+ level,'D','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Turkish') day_no , 
       to_char(sysdate+ level,'Day','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=Turkish') day
  from dual 
connect by level <= 7 
order by 1;
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR( datevalue, 'D' )` is dependent on the `NLS_TERRITORY` session parameter and different territories have different first days of the week. `TO_CHAR( datevalue, 'DAY' )` is dependent on the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` session parameter. Users can set both of these parameters in their own sessions so this method is going to have issues when used internationally.

Comment: @MT0 I know, that's dependent on the NLS_TERRITORY, but doesn't make difference for this case, provided NLS_TERRITORY parameter set according to the local conventions by DBA. I mean it's not the task of a Software Developer but the DBA. ( By the way, the Question became quite different than before ) .

Comment: No - [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c569b/3) nothing has changed on the server in that fiddle but the user has changed their own session parameters and the query is now giving different results. It does not matter what the server settings are as the user's session parameters will override them.

Comment: @MT0 I'm telling the same thing but not the task of a software developer. OK, that's a different style, may be considerable as another way. I see, you mean this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c12e/1

Comment: Using explicit NLS parameters in the 3rd arguments for `TO_CHAR` is one way to solve the issue (but you then need to always to include that argument rather than the session default and make sure the querying users always use a consistent parameter value). You should update your answer to mention this as a solution when the query is going to be run internationally.

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to stick to day names rather than a calculated offset, you can use [the optional third argument to the `to_char()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-datetime.html#GUID-0C3EEFD1-AE3D-452D-BF23-2FC95664E78F) to avoid [the session-NLS issues](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-E118F121-A0E1-4784-A685-D35CE64B4557) @MTO has pointed out:

```
to_char(sysdate, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH'
```

will give you the full day name in English. (Note that you can't use this to get a query-specific interpretation of the `D` element; also the `FM` removes the usual right-padding to make all the names the same length; doesn't really matter here...)

As a demo with your data in a CTE, and column names changes to be valid:

```
with your_table (user_id, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday)
as (
            select 123456, null, 18, null, 15, null, null, 11 from dual
  union all select 789023, 18, null, 3, 15, null, null, 11 from dual
)
select user_id
from your_table
where case to_char(sysdate, 'FMDAY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
    when 'SUNDAY' then sunday
    when 'MONDAY' then monday
    when 'TUESDAY' then tuesday
    when 'WEDNESDAY' then wednesday
    when 'THURSDAY' then thursday
    when 'FRIDAY' then friday
    when 'SATURDAY' then saturday
  end is not null;

   USER_ID
----------
    123456
    789023
```

which finds both users as today is Wednesday.